# How to implement Redux Slicer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Hello I am working on a Registration app, I was using useState hook to set the user information
and this way it works fine

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Registration = (props) => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    password_confirmation: '',
  });


  const { email, password, password_confirmation } = user;

  const handlChange = (event) => {
    setUser({ ...user, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });

  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    axios
      .post(
        'http://localhost:3001/registrations',
        {
          user: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            password_confirmation: password_confirmation,
          },
        },
        { withCredentials: true },
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.status === 'created') {
          props.handleSuccessfulAuth(response.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('registration error', error);
      });
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChange={handlChange}
          required
        />

        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChange={handlChange}
          required
        />

        <input
          type="password"
          name="password_confirmation"
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
          value={password_confirmation}
          onChange={handlChange}
          required
        />

        <button tupe="submit">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Registration;
```

now the issue is that I have to use Redux to manage the state ,so created a slicer
here is my slicer ,
the problem i have is that i don't know how to connect redux to my registration component,
for example I am assuming that the information provided in the form is the payload so i will be passing it to my reducer as the action.payload and i think i am setting the state with the information from the payload.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
  password_confirmation: '',
};

const registrationSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'registration',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUsers: (state, action) => {
      const { email, password, password_confirmation } = action.payload;
      state = {
        email,
        password,
        password_confirmation,
      };
    },
  },
});

export const { setUsers } = registrationSlice.actions;

export default registrationSlice.reducer;
```

the problem is how do i connect this to my component, I read in the Redux Toolkit website I have to use dispatch and useSelector,
so that is what i think i am doing here but is not working,
I am stuck at this point and don't know how to solve it. Can someone please help me understand how to fix it and make it work.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { setUsers } from '../../features/user/registrationSlice';

const Registration = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  // const { email, password, password_confirmation } = user;

  const handlChange = (event) => {
    dispatch(setUsers({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    axios
      .post(
        'http://localhost:3001/registrations',
        {
          user: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            password_confirmation: password_confirmation,
          },
        },
        { withCredentials: true },
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.status === 'created') {
          props.handleSuccessfulAuth(response.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('registration error', error);
      });
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChange={handlChange}
          required
        />

        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChange={handlChange}
          required
        />

        <input
          type="password"
          name="password_confirmation"
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
          value={password_confirmation}
          onChange={handlChange}
          required
        />

        <button tupe="submit">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Registration;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that your reducer case is expecting a "full set" of state properties to update all at once but the UI is dispatching actions for each sub-state individually.

## Solution

I suggest updating the reducer, or rather, add a new reducer to handle setting individual state properties. This leaves the possibility to set the entire state if you want.

```
const registrationSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'registration',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUsers: (state, action) => {
      const { email, password, password_confirmation } = action.payload;
      state {
        email,
        password,
        password_confirmation,
      };
    },
    setUserProperty: (state, action) => {
      const { name, value } = action.payload;
      state[name] = value;
    },
  },
});
```

And dispatch the new `setUserProperty` action.

```
const handlChange = (event) => {
  dispatch(setUserProperty({
    name: event.target.name,
    value: event.target.value,
  }));
};
```

Since you are using Redux-toolkit you may want to eventually consider moving all the asynchronous `axios` POST request logic into a thunk via the [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk). The thunk will have access to the store to get the user values and make the asynchronous calls. This will allow you to further decouple the `Registration` component from auth/registration logic and your redux state.

Comment: quick question, when compiling the code is telling that email, password, and password_confirmation are not defined. How can I fix it to it reads the value from the form?

Comment: @Cosmel You've commented out the line that defines them: `// const { email, password, password_confirmation } = user;`.

Comment: yes that worked for me, now I have to be honest I have no clue how to apply [createAsyncThun](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) to the project, any ideas how I can achieve it?

Comment: @Cosmel That'd be off-topic for this question, but mostly it'd be copying the axios request logic into the callback of `createAsyncThunk` and returning the `response.data` value instead of calling `props.handleSuccessfulAuth(response.data);`. Add new cases to handle the pending, fulfilled, or rejected return values in the `extraReducers` section of the state slice. If you are implementing this and have issue then create a new post here on SO, and feel free to (at) me in a comment there or ping me here with a link to the new question, and I can take a look.

Comment: i created another post, here is the link to the question [how to implement createAsyncThunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68202470/how-to-implement-createasyncthunk)